Browser could not load the image
I have been having issues loading images to the webpage from the folder.
I tried to get it from the image folder, directly from the same location as html file and link from the existing website. Only pictures from the website link work and display an image. For the image from the folder and direct location there is nothing being displayed.
Can someone please explain what is that I do wrong?
I have tried all of the known to me approaches but only one of them seems to be workingfolder with html file , image subfolder 

Is your server hosting the images at the addresses you say they are? What http server are you using? (Something with typescript, I can see...). Usually, http servers don't just let anyone access anything in your filesystem. You usually have to either explicitly host them at a given route, or put them in a folder made for this purpose.

Hi I am trying to learn API and this is just a simple html code to use for Deno server.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
